# How to give the users the ability to update their information

Tags: php, mysqli

Hey guys I am new to programming and I have a quick question and hopefully it isnt too much. I am trying to give users of my test website to have the ability to update their information. I use the following code:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'testpass', 'testdatabase') 
or die(mysqli_error());


echo "<h2>How would you like to update your account $_SESSION[username]?</h2>";
$display = <<<END
<h4> Update your username here: <br/></h4>
<form method="POST" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
<input type="text" name="update_username"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>



END;
echo $display;
$update_username = $_POST['update_username'];
$current_username = $_SESSION['username'];


$sql_update = "UPDATE users SET username = '$update_username' WHERE username = '$current_username'";
$result_update = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_update) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

The code above updates their information, but it only updates once. When I check the database after updating it, it changed to whatever I changed it too. Then I try and changed it again but it doesnt change, so I log out and log back in. When I log back in I change it, but this time, when I look at the database, there is no username. I log back out and log back in again. I change it again and it actually changes. I have to go through this same process everytime I try and change the username(or any other sort of information) and it gets very annoying. Do you guys have any ideas on why it is doing this?Thanks!

Comment: Did you start the session and for all pages using sessions? You may also need to destroy the session on logout.

Comment: Use a conditional statement,

Comment: I'm thinking you may have  a sessions cache issue. You'll need to show relevant code for pages used. Plus, using `isset()` for $_POST and $_SESSION variables.

Comment: The session is destroyed on the logout and yes the session has been started

Comment: conditional statement? sorry guys I am really new to php.

Comment: `if( isset($_SESSION['username']) ){...}`

Comment: if ((isset($_SESSION['email'])) && (isset($_SESSION['password'])))

Comment: that is what i have at the very top of my code right after session_start()

Comment: Where does `$_SESSION['username']` come into play, checked for and assigned? Plus, do NOT store passwords in sessions. Ever heard of sessions hijacking? Keep doing that, and you will; the hard way.

Comment: Like I said I am very new to programming. See like I dont know this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For database stuff, you want to track everything by IDs, so the first field in most every table will be 'id', set as primary key with auto increment.  Then when updating you would do WHERE id = $userID.  When they login, the user id would be stored in the session as well as username, and any queries would reference them by id.  It also makes it a lot easier/faster to query/track stuff when you start doing table joins

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
END;
echo $display;
$update_username = $_POST['update_username'];
$current_username = $_SESSION['username'];
$current_id = mysql query select id where username = $current_username

$sql_update = "UPDATE users SET username = '$update_username' WHERE id = '$current_id'";
$result_update = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_update) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

hope you can fix my pseudo code in `$current_id` variable